# Was javascript argument default?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arguments

Is there a way to tell the difference between this

```
((a=true)=>{return a})(true)
```

And this?

```
((a=true)=>{return a})()
```

They both return true - how can I tell whether that true is coming from the default value of the argument, or from the value passed in to that parameter?

- Is it possible from *outside* the function?
- Is it possible from *inside* the function?

Comment: if you use a "regular" function rather than an arrow function, you can check `arguments.length`

Comment: @JaromandaX. It would be worth to mention that even `arguments` object is available only in non-strict mode.

Comment: Using `arguments` in strict mode functions is perfectly valid.

Comment: @loganfsmyth. No, you can use `arguments` object, but you cannot access a lot of its properties. For example, `caller`, `callee`, and `arguments` properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions.

Comment: @FREE_AND_OPEN_SOURCE But accessing `.length` like in JaromandaX's suggestion is fine in strict mode.

Comment: @FREE_AND_OPEN_SOURCE - `arguments.length` is perfectly cromulent in "strict mode", so mentioning it's unavailability would be erroneous

Comment: @loganfsmyth. Correct, but I mean, exploiting properties of `arguments` object may sometimes expose possibilities such as reading source code of currently executing function or similar things. Anyway, I agree, I don't see how that may influence finding answers to that particular question.

Comment: In general, you should not use default values when you need to distinguish those cases. What is your [actual problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)?

Comment: What do you mean by "*from outside the function*"? The caller surely knows what was passed, and every other code doesn't even know about the call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to tell the difference between these two?

No. Arrow function doesn't support argument object, so there is no way to check this.

But, if you are using non-arrow functions, you can get arguments number from inside the function. For example:

```
(function(a=true){return arguments.length;})(); // 0
(function(a=true){return arguments.length;})(true); // 1
```

You can easily figure out how to extend this to multiple arguments.

Comment: it may be worth mentioning that accessing `arguments.length` is perfectly valid in `strict mode`

Comment: @JaromandaX. Ok, updated. But I mean, exploiting properties of `arguments` object may sometimes expose possibilities such as reading source code of currently executing function or similar things. Anyway, I agree, I don't see how that may influence finding answers to that particular question.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot tell the difference in your specific examples, and there is no way to tell from outside the function definitely. The only exposed info is what you explicitly expose with your return value, which is just the boolean.

From *inside* the function, you can tell the difference if you rewrite your logic. You could change your function from

```
((a=true)=>{
  return a;
})(true)
```

to

```
((...args)=>{
  const a = args[0] === undefined ? true : args[0];

  if (args.length > 0) console.log("passed arg");
  else console.log("passed no arg");

  return a;
})(true)
```

Note that you cannot combine this with default value syntax, so if you'd have to rewrite it to use rest syntax.

Alternatively, you could use a normal function instead of an arrow, and use `arguments`, however that is also a potentially difficult change if your real-world case relies on the arrow-function's lexical `this`. e.g.

```
(function(a = true)=>{
  if (arguments.length > 0) console.log("passed arg");
  else console.log("passed no arg");

  return a;
})(true)
```

Comment: Instead of `arguments.length > 0` I'd check for `arguments[0] !== undefined` as that's what the default initialiser uses

Comment: My assumption was that the question was detecting the presence of an arg being passed, so it should count even if the user did `foo(undefined)`. But it was a bit unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Although not ideal in every way, one solution might be:

```
(a=undefined) => {
  let is_default = false; 
  if (a === undefined) {
    is_default = true;
    a = true;
  } 

  return a
}
```

Comment: The main downside is that this doesn't catch if you pass an argument but the value is undefined.

Comment: A default value of `undefined` is pretty useless, as that's the default default value. (The only difference is the arity of the function)

Comment: Yes, for pure JS it wouldn't make a difference. I did it for 2 reasons, one it makes it obvious that there is a default intent and for the benefit of some type inference checkers

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use arrow functions, you can achieve a robust (if convoluted) result using `Symbol` and a wrapping IIFE

```
var fn = ((def) => 
    (a = def) => {
        if(a === def) {
            console.log('defaulted');
            a = true;
        }
        console.log('a is', a);
    }
)(Symbol());
```

both `fn()` and `fn(true)` will result in `a is true` - however, `fn()` will also output `defaulted` and then set `a = true` - though this last step I guess doesn't have to done, depends on what the real content of the real function you really want to "detect" this in

Or, a better way as pointed out by @Bergi (I keep forgetting about the block scope in ES6+ :D )

```
var fn; 
{ 
    const def = Symbol(); 
    fn = (a=def) => {
        if(a === def) {
            console.log('defaulted');
            a = true;
        }
        console.log('a is', a);
    }; 
}
```

Comment: How about `var fn; { const def = Symbol(); fn = (a=def) => {…}; }`?